# Need more float precision

Tags: arbitrary-precision, physics, physicalconstants-package

I have a Physics problem which huge and tiny numbers and Mathematica just gives me a speed of my particles which is the speed of light. Then $1/\sqrt{1-v^2/c^2}$ becomes singular.

If I use smaller values for my radius `r`, it works, but with the radius of 300 light years, I just get error messages.

Is there some way to increase the precision or something like that?

http://wstaw.org/m/2012/06/16/Bildschirmfoto4.png

Comment: Have you tried using e.g. `q = SetPrecision[q, 50]` on all numeric variables?  You could also try `Rationalize`.  Be aware that either of these will be generating false precision.

Comment: I tried `SetPrecision[number, Infinity]` and it works now. I am aware that the precision of my answer is not correct, but I just need it for a Physics homework example.

Comment: okay, I'll post that as an answer.

Comment: Did you consider using Hartree Units? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_units#Summary_table

Comment: @belisarius: Interesting! I usually only use SI since I avoid any conversion then. I'll put that in the back of my mind though.

Comment: As this is homework, maybe it is constructed to illustrate how the appropriate choice of units will help with the precision in computations...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`SetPrecision`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/SetPrecision.html) to set the interpreted precision of a numeric value, or [`Rationalize`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Rationalize.html) to convert it into an exact value.

Be cautious about manufacturing false precision.